# How can I make a search button that can combine my site url + the text on the input?

Tags: html

This is an example url: `https://mysitename.com`

And I typed this text on search box: `abcd123.html`

When I click the search button or a normal button, i want it to **exactly** go to:
`https://mysitename.com/abcd123.html`

And if possible, I want to hide the `.html`. So that only the `abcd123` will be typed on the search box. But the result will be the same.

I've tried this code but the only problem is it directs me to `https://mysitename.com/?n=abcd123.html`. There is a `?n=` ruining the url.

```
<form class="test" role="search" method="get"
action="https://mysitename.com"><input type="search" id="testSearch" class="Search" name="n" value="" 
placeholder="Search Here...">
```

Comment: I think the reason you're ending up in your https://mysitename.com is because that's the action on your form. The way it works is that you click the link. It goes back to your page and looks for something to do with the parameter abcd123.html. The ?n= part is what passes your parameter to your page. You'll need code (i.e., javascript or other) to process your request with the supplied parameter.

Comment: You've picked the far inferiour solution. My answer works without using a hard coded site url, and it also works if you simply press enter in the search field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Listen to the `submit` event on the `form`.
2. Prevent it when it occurs.
3. Redirect to `location.origin + '/' + document.getElementById('testSearch').value`.

```js
document.getElementById('searchform').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  location.href = `${location.origin}/${document.getElementById('testSearch').value}`;
});
```

```html
<form class="test" role="search" method="get" action="https://mysitename.com" id="searchform">
  <input type="search" id="testSearch" class="Search" name="" value="" placeholder="Search Here...">
</form>
```

For the above to work, follow these steps:

1. In the directory where your HTML file is, create a subdirectory `./js`.
2. Inside that new directory, create a new file named `search.js`.
3. Copy the above Javascript into that file. Don't forget to save.
4. In your HTML, inside the `<head>` section, include the newly created JS file like this:

   ```
   <script src="./js/search.js" defer></script>
   ```

Comment: thanks, but still direct me to `https://mysitename.com?` ,

Comment: Have you put the Javascript in an external file and included the Javascript in your page? The redirect you see cannot happen if the JS is executed properly, due to `event.preventDefault();`. Put the JS in a file called `search.js`, then include this tag in the `head` section of your HTML: `<script src="./path/to/search.js" defer="defer"></script>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="search" id="testSearch" class="Search" name="" value="" 
placeholder="Search Here...">
<button id= "search" onclick="search()" >Search</button>
<script>
function search() {
  var searchtxt = document.getElementById('testSearch').value
window.location.href = "https://mysiteurl.com/"+ searchtxt + ".html";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Its really works fine, its just my mistake,I only used the Enter key, without clicking the button using mouse, btw I put the java to head section. Thank You

Comment: but how can I add more 3 ID's ? ... on this:
 
```<p>Enter the IMDB ID,Season and Episodes of the Movie Below</p>
<input type="search" id="imdbseries" class="Search" name="" value="" 
placeholder="IMDB ID">
<input type="search" id="season" class="Search" name="" value="" 
placeholder="SEASON">
<input type="search" id="episode" class="Search" name="" value="" 
placeholder="EPISODE">
<button id= "search" onclick="search()" >Watch Now</button>
```